# Sound output buffer flush

Tags: java

I have a jsp that plays wav file through java class in GlassFish. I have used SourceDataline methods:

```
start();
drain();
close();
```

The wav file is played properly. For stopping I used:

```
stop();
flush();
close();
```

But the play continues with the rest of data inside the output buffer. I went through the documents over www.oracle.com about SourceDataline methods. There it is said that flush() will discard the data inside the SourceDataline object but not the data already inside the output buffer.

Now I want to flush out the data from the output buffer so that there will be no overlapping of sound during the next start.
I searched on JavaScript also but without help.

Comment: Just curious, what does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: *"I have a jsp that plays wav file"*  Where?  On the server (where it can drive the system operators mad)?  On the client (where it would need an applet)?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a shot in the dark, but could work: the documentation for [`TargetDataLine.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> Reads audio data from the data line's input buffer. (...) However, if the data line is closed, stopped, drained, or flushed before the requested amount has been read, the method no longer blocks, but returns the number of bytes read thus far.

So, maybe you can try to gain access to the TargetDataLine(s) being used (maybe using [`Mixer.getTargetLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html#getTargetLines%28%29)) and try to act on them too (stopping, flushing etc). I'm not sure, however, if there would be any side-effects of doing that (or even if it's possible at all).

Is there any additional info about your problem you can share? You mentioned jsp, GlassFish and JavaScript, so I'm guessing you're either using an Applet to play the file, or maybe just using Java to mix server-side but sending the resulting file to be handled by the browser. Is any of this correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using methods of AudioInputStream class in Java and not Applet. I am sampling the audio on server and sending the result to the client browser. I will implement your solution and let you know. Thank you very much.